# How to configure angular2-typescript application to run in VS Code

Tags: typescript, angular, visual-studio-code

I am really lost here, please help me understand this configuration,

```
launch.json 
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/workspace/angular/app/main.ts",
```

I saw many variations for the "program" attribute and I have no idea what the purpose of this attribute.

this is the only way it works for me:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/workspace/angular/node_modules/lite-server/bin/lite-server",
```

but it wont let me debug the application and the browser open with 
"http://localhost:3000" which is not the full address of the application

I saw examples that looks like:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/app/app.js",
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/app/app.ts",
```

but it never runs, I get "System is not defined" errors, what main.ts needs to contain?

I even saw:

"program": "http://localhost/blabla/index.html",

what it the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Chrome debugger extension for vscode ?

1. Make sure you have source maps enabled
2. Add these configurations to `launch.json`

`{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "url": "<url of the open browser tab, you wanna connect to"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to url with files served from ./out",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "url": "<url of the open browser tab, you wanna connect to",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/out"
        }
    ]
}`

3. Start Chrome with remote debugging enabled, `chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that's is actually pretty old post, I switched to Webstorm.